# Adding Geotiff tags

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I am using Geotools GeoTiffWriter to write geotiff and it is working well for the most part. I have found an issue writing images with NAD83 2011 projections. gdalinfo shows the projection information. However, ArcGIS does not recognize it. (ArcMap does recognize older NAD83 projections, I have output though). I believe the issue can be fixed by adding additional GeoKeys* to the geotiff. Can this be done with Geotools and/or suggestions on how I might do this?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Desktop didn't recognize NAD 2011 until (I think) version 10.1, it sounds like you must be on an older version. You can either upgrade or import the coordinate system definition manually. [This GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43977) explains the latter option and provides the file you'll need to add both the coordinate system and some geographic transformations for the new CS. If you're on ArcGIS < 10.1 though, I'd upgrade if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just glanced over the GeoTiffWriter and see this method:

`/**
 * Allows to setup metadata by leveraging on Ascii TIFF Tags.
 * @param name is the Ascii TIFF Tag identifier.
 *     It can be a String representing:
 *     1) a simple Integer (referring to a tag ID) (in that case it will refer to the BaselineTIFFTagSet 
 *     2) OR an identifier in the form:
 *     TIFFTagSet:TIFFTagID. As an instance: "BaselineTIFFTagSet:305" in order to add the Copyright info.
 * @param value is the value to be assigned to that tag.
 * @see GeoTiffIIOMetadataEncoder.TagSet
 */
@Override
public void setMetadataValue(String name, String value) throws IOException`

I cannot guarantee it will work, but it seems like it might?